# Second derivative change of variables

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

If I want to express $f''(x)+Af(x)=0$ in terms of a new variable $t$ where $t= cos(x)$ (So I want a new ODE with the same function $f(t)$ in terms of t now). How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to this is the Chain Rule. The prime notation isn't the best in these situations.

$$\mathrm{f}'(x) = \frac{\mathrm{df}}{\mathrm{d}x}$$

From this point, you can apply the chain rule:

$$\frac{\mathrm{df}}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\mathrm{df}}{\mathrm{d}t} \times \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}x}$$

You have $t=\cos x$ which means that $\displaystyle{\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}x}=-\sin x}$. Using the identity $\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x \equiv 1$ gives
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}x} = \mp\sqrt{1-t^2}$$

Putting this together, gives (using a dot for the time derivative):
$$\mathrm{f}'(x) = \mp\sqrt{1-t^2} \times \dot{\mathrm{f}}(t)$$

To find the second derivative, you can apply the Chain Rule a second time:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}x} \times \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}$$

To find $\mathrm{f}''(x)$, you need to compute:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}x} \times \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\mp\sqrt{1-t^2} \times \dot{\mathrm{f}}(t)\right) = \sqrt{1-t^2} \times \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\sqrt{1-t^2} \times \dot{\mathrm{f}}(t)\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Apply chain rule twice. Since $x = \arccos{t}$

$$f'(x) = \frac{df}{dt}\,  \frac{dt}{dx} = - \sin{x}\,  f'(t) = \mp \sqrt{1-\cos^2{x}}\,  f'(t) = \mp \sqrt{1-t^2} \, f'(t). $$

Now follow the same steps to compute $f''(t)$.

Comment: Your expressions are incorrect.

Comment: Of course. Just edited. Thanks @FlybyNight

Comment: There's still an error.

Comment: Omg. I am not at my best today...